# > Task :app:checkDebugManifest FAILED //@React Native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

react-native doctor said that it is fine.
But when I run "npx react-native run-android"...
The terminal say "3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date" and returns error.
Then, Most serious probrem is this,

```
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest FAILED

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:checkDebugManifest' (type 'CheckManifest').
  - Type 'CheckManifest': property 'manifest' has @Input annotation used on property of type 'File'. A property of type 'File' annotated with @Input cannot determine how to interpret the file. Possible solutions: Annotate with @InputFile for regular files or annotate with @InputDirectory for directories or if you want to track the path, return File.absolutePath as a String and keep @Input. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0-20210303140106+0000/userguide/validation_problems.html#incorrect_use_of_input_annotation for more details about this problem.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

What they mean?
What I should do?

Maybe here's an almost perfect answer.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/validation_problems.html#incorrect_use_of_input_annotation

> **Incorrect use of the @Input annotation**
> This error indicates that a property is annotated with @Input, but that it should be annotated with @InputFile or @InputDirectory instead.
> If you use the @Input annotation on a file-based property, Gradle wouldn’t consider the file contents, or the directory contents, as inputs, as you might expect.
> To fix this problem, you need to tell Gradle if the file property represents an input file, in which case you should annotate it with @InputFile, or a directory, in which case it should be annotated with @InputDirectory. If what you really wanted to say is that the actual file path is an input, then you should return a String instead which corresponds to the absolute path of the file.

But... Embarrassingly, I couldn't figure this out.

I guessed there is a file called "checkDebugManifest" in the app directory, and maybe it had the error that caused by the wrong type of program. I thought that rewriting it should fix the problem.
But there is no such file anywhere.
What do I need to rewrite?
And how?

[Image: Terminal said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFxaJ.jpg)